# Is it safe to directly upgrade from angular xx version to angular 16?

Tags: angular, upgrade

If its not safe, why not? Can we go through the package.json and update packages for each library manually?

Comment: Please follow the Angular upgrade recommendations: https://update.angular.io/ It's not recommended to upgrade more than one major version at a time.

Comment: @Roy Kindly please mention the reasons also.